En Genexus 17 con Work With Plus en .Net C# Imagen
Trabajo con Genexus 17 con Work With Plus .Net C#. En una transacción tengo un atributo tipo Imege, necesito obtener el path de donde la obtengo con su nombre para copiarla en otro directorio de mi equipo, como lo hago? Intenté obtener el path y me da uno temporal y por otra parte quise copirlo con GXCopyFile y me da el error cs(1481,18): error CS0234.
Alguien podrá ayudarme por favor

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! en genexus (la herramienta magica que genera codigo) o en c#? como lo intentaste?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
